# Finite automata as dynamical systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, automata, finite-automata

In abstract (deterministic finite) automata theory the set of states of an automaton is an arbitrary set Q, and the transistion function  is a specific set δ ⊆ Q × Σ × Q (with alphabet Σ, i.e. another set).

In a "real" automaton - seen as a dynamical system - its states are configurations of the system. These configurations may determine the transition function - seen as a dynamical process - in a traceable way.

I am looking for references where the states of an deterministic automaton are treated or at least discussed as configurations of a dynamical system - and not only as arbitrary atomic entities (symbols). Where should I look at, how could I search?

Comment: I am not sure if it is relevant to you, but systems that combine discrete and continuous behaviour are called [hybrid systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_system). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the following papers. I suggest you to read [2] first: it is shorter and more elementary than [1].

[1] Béal, Marie-Pierre; Perrin, Dominique. [Symbolic dynamics and finite automata](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~perrin/Recherche/HandbookAutomata/symbolicdynamics.pdf). Handbook of formal languages, Vol. 2, 463--505, Springer, Berlin, 1997.

[2] Perrin, Dominique. [Symbolic dynamics and finite automata](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eperrin/Recherche/Publications/MFCS95/SymbolicDynamicsMFCS.dvi). Mathematical foundations of computer science 1995 (Prague), 94--104, Lecture Notes in Comput. Sci., 969, Springer, Berlin, 1995.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be quite what you're looking for, but graph dynamical systems apply dynamical systems theory to automata theory. Particularly, cellular automata. There is a book on this: [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Sequential-Dynamical-Systems-Universitext/dp/0387306544](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387306544)

Much of the research in this field comes from the Network Dynamics and Simulation Science Lab (NDSSL) at Virginia Tech. Henning Mortveit and Chris Barrett are good names for literature.